# Oracle SQL : timestamps in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, sql-timestamp

I need to look up rows within a particular time frame.

```
select * 
from TableA 
where startdate >= '12-01-2012 21:24:00' 
  and startdate <= '12-01-2012 21:25:33'
```

I.e.: I need to look up rows with timestamp precision of SECONDS. How do I achieve this?

FYI: The `startdate` column is of type `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: What is the schema of your table?

Comment: What happens if you use the query in the question?

Comment: The field in question is "TIMESTAMP",

Answer (score 160, accepted):

### to_timestamp()

You need to use `to_timestamp()` to convert your string to a proper `timestamp` value:

```
to_timestamp('12-01-2012 21:24:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

### to_date()

If your column is of type `DATE` (which also supports seconds), you need to use `to_date()`

```
to_date('12-01-2012 21:24:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

### Example

To get this into a `where` condition use the following:

```
select * 
from TableA 
where startdate >= to_timestamp('12-01-2012 21:24:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  and startdate <= to_timestamp('12-01-2012 21:25:33', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

### Note

You never need to use `to_timestamp()` on a column that is of type `timestamp`.

Comment: I get an error: "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
here is my query: "select * from TableA where To_Timestamp(startdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') > To_Timestamp('12-01-2012 21:24:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');"

Comment: The value in the field is "12-JAN-12 09.24.06.355000000 PM" & its a TimeStamp field in oracle db

Comment: @user1095057: you don't not need to apply `to_timestamp()` on your column but on your input values. See my edit.

Answer (score 17):

For everyone coming to this thread with fractional seconds in your timestamp use:

`to_timestamp('2018-11-03 12:35:20.419000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')`