# how do I write an sql where filter that will return rows where the timestamp is greater than a given date and time?

Tags: sql

how do I write an sql where filter that will return rows where the timestamp is greater than a given date and time?

for example I want all rows with a timestamp after

```
monday 5:30 pm
```

Comment: provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: Which database do you use? Answers depend on it.

Comment: Which Monday?  Which database?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATETIME > YOURDATETIME
```

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATETIME > '2020-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can use

```
select * from db
where startdate >= to_timestamp('2020-01-01 17:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

Its very simular issue as [Oracle SQL : timestamps in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855378/oracle-sql-timestamps-in-where-clause)

Comment: This is not PL/SQL. This is SQL. In Oracle you would use `to_timstamp` if you got a datetime string from somewhere. For a fixed datetime you'd rather use a standard compliant timstamp literal: `where startdate >= timestamp '2020-01-01 17:30:00'`.